# JavaScript - Adding an object to the end of an array through a input field

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, electron

I am trying to *dynamically* add an object with values from an input field to the end of an array using JavaScript. The only catch is that **I'm trying to do it with an input field**. Here's what I want to happen:

1. The user types in something in a text field
2. My program already adds a unique ID for it
3. **Add it to the end of an array** in the form of a object
4. Keep on adding objects to that array

This is what I *want* in my **JSON file**:

```js
{
  "list": [{
    "id": 0,
    "description": "Task #1 Description"
  }, {
    "id": 1,
    "description": "Task #2 Description"
  }, {
    "id": 3,
    "description": "Task #3 Description"
  }]
}
```

What I am *currently getting* is:

```
{
  "list": [{
    "id": 0,
    "description": "Task #1 Description"
  }, ]
}
```

Every time I add a new Task, it **replaces** the one that is already there.

Here is my **JavaScript code**:

```
  // This is the counter
  var indentification = 0;

  // This is the submit button
  var submit = document.getElementById("submit");

  // This is the text field
  var content = document.getElementById("text");

  submit.onclick = function() {
      id = indentification++;
      description = content.value;

      var task = {
          list: []
      }

      task.list.push({id, description});
      var jsonifyTask = JSON.stringify(task);
      fs.writeFile("tasks.json", jsonifyTask, "utf8");
  }
```

I would *really appreciate* it if anyone could help me out. I've spent **hours** trying to figure it out. Thanks!

Comment: NEVER call anything in a form for submit. Instead use the form onsubmit and return false or preventDefault

Answer (score 2):

The problem is here:

```
var task = {
      list: []
  }
task.list.push({id, description});
```

Each time you do this your list become empty then add new item.

Comment: Indeed. The variable task should be created outside of the event listener.

Answer (score 2):

change to this

```
  // This is the counter
  var indentification = 0;

  // This is the submit button
  var submit = document.getElementById("submit");

  // This is the text field
  var content = document.getElementById("text");
  var task = {
    list: []
  }
  submit.onclick = function() {
      id = indentification++;
      description = content.value;

      task.list.push({id, description});
      var jsonifyTask = JSON.stringify(task);
      fs.writeFile("tasks.json", jsonifyTask, "utf8"); // what're you doing here, browser do not allow write file to disk
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of things that you need to consider here:

1. Form submit must be refreshing the page and resetting your global variables. Thus you need to prevent default action on click of submit.
2. (as mentioned in earlier answers) The list is being initiated on every click. You will need to initialize the variable task outside the onClick function

   ```
   // This is the counter
   var indentification = 0;

   // This is the submit button
   var submit = document.getElementById("submit");

   // This is the text field
   var content = document.getElementById("text");
   //initialize outside the on click function
   var task = {
           list: []
      }

   submit.onclick = function(e) {
     //This prevents page refresh on form submission and preserves the global variable states
     e.preventDefault();
     id = indentification++;
     description = content.value;



     task.list.push({id, description});
     var jsonifyTask = JSON.stringify(task);
     fs.writeFile("tasks.json", jsonifyTask, "utf8");
   }
   ```

This should hopefully solve your problem.

Comment: I would suggest `var form = document.getElementById("formID"); form.onsubmit-function....`

Comment: @mplungjan is there any additional benefit of attaching the function to form submit rather than click of submit button?

Comment: You want to intercept the submission not the click. If you have a submit button, intercept the submit event. If not, have a type="button". Additional reason is enter on a single field will submit the form too, even without a button

Answer (score 0):

```
// This is the counter
var indentification = 0;

// This is the submit button
var submit = document.getElementById("submit");

// This is the text field
var content = document.getElementById("text");

submit.addEventHandler("click", function() {
    id = indentification++;
    description = content.value;
    task.list.push({id, description});
    var jsonifyTask = JSON.stringify(task);
    fs.writeFile("tasks.json", jsonifyTask, "utf8");
}
```

Comment: And cancel the default action